# How to create sha1 hashing for the entire row in a RDD/Dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a dataframe with  one schema. The existing dataframe is already having 50 columns .Now I want to add a new column in the existing dataframe. The new column name is "hashing_id" and the logic for this hashing_id is sha1(row). How do I achive this?

I tried the below code . These below two methods are inside a trait which is used by the main Class . This trait also extends Serializable

```
 def addHashingKey():DataFrame={
val sha1 = java.security.MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1")
val enCoder = new sun.misc.BASE64Encoder()
//enCoder.encode(sha1.digest(row.mkString.getBytes))
createDataFrame(df.map(row => {
        Row.fromSeq(row.toSeq ++ enCoder.encode(sha1.digest(row.mkString.getBytes)))
}), df.schema.add("hashing_id", StringType))

 }


def createDataFrame(rdd: RDD[Row], schema: StructType): DataFrame = {
sqlContext.createDataFrame(rdd, schema)
}
```

How do I achieve sha1 using rdd ?

Could someone help me on this

When I run the code , it throws below exception

```
 17/09/12 13:45:20 ERROR yarn.ApplicationMaster: User class threw exception: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable
 org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable

 Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: sun.misc.BASE64Encoder
 Serialization stack:
 - object not serializable (class: sun.misc.BASE64Encoder, value:   sun.misc.BASE64Encoder@46c0813)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you try something like this, it seems to be working for me in a few test i've just run:

```
 val newDF = sqlContext.createDataFrame(
rdd.map(x => Row(x.toSeq ++ Seq(x.toSeq.hashCode()): _*)), StructType(schema.iterator.toSeq ++ Seq(StructField("hashing_id", StringType, true))))
```

Obviously you need to replace hashCode for the hash function that you need

Edit: To use your sha1 function

Define your function in another class

```
object Encoder {
  def sha1(s: Row): String = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1").digest(s.mkString.getBytes()).toString
}
```

Then in your original class you can call your function as follows

```
   val newDF = sqlContext.createDataFrame(wordsRDD.map(x => Row(x.toSeq ++ Seq(Encoder.sha1(x)): _*)), StructType(schema.iterator.toSeq ++ Seq(StructField("hashing_id", StringType, true)))).rdd.collect()
```

Comment: I tried by adding sha1 hashing and it throws java.io.NotSerializableException

Comment: You need to move your function to a top-level class. I'll update my answer with an example